# Missing Attachment. Get all posts from Wordpress do not show the attachment

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm new to Wordpress and i'm trying to get all posts out in my php file.

```
global $post;
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 10,
   'order'=> 'ASC',
   'orderby' => 'date'
);


$postslist = get_posts( $args );
if($postslist) {
foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
    setup_postdata( $post );
    ?>
        <p><?php the_date(); ?></p>
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        <?php the_attachment_link($post->ID, false);  ?>
<?php
  endforeach;
}

  wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

The title, date and description do come out but not the attachements. I need to show all posts also the posts with no attachements. Right now it says "Missing Attachment".

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: "Missing Attachment" means to post thumbnail right ?

Comment: The attachment is a media in the post. The text from Wordpress looks something like this: 

<p>some text.</p>

<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-42" src="http://192.168.87.200/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/treeimage.jpg" alt="" width="480" height="640" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try like this...**

```
  <?php
$args = array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>10, 'orderby'=>'date', 'order'=>'ASC');
$post_list = get_posts($args);
foreach($post_list as $post) {
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
?>
<p><?php the_time('Y/m/d'); ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $post->post_title;?></p>
    <p><?php echo $post->post_excerpt;?></p>
    <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $url ;?>" />
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I just tried. The text: "Missing Attachment" is now gone but the attachement is still not showing?

Comment: now i'm just getting the title from the post and not the description, attachements or dates :-S

Comment: Now i'm getting the date and the title of the page :-S When i'm looking in the inspection tool in google it makes the <img> but the src attribute is unknown.

Comment: So your post does not have featured image.that's it

Comment: No it got an image inside the text. I just added the image as a featured image and then your code is working but do the image have to be a featured image before it will show in Wordpress. It's not enough for the user just to add the media?

Comment: Then you need to check that how you had upload image in wordpress editor. bcoz, wordpress automatically create img tag when you upload media in post editor

Comment: Okay, thanks for all your help and a working solution :-)